# vb.net arcobjects "current no topology available"

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, topology

I am using ArcMap add-in to perform a topology validation. I have defined a topology in the geodatabase and add it in ArcMap TOC. When I try to get the current topology using ArcObjects, I get this message : "current no topology available".

My code is shown below:

```
Public Sub ReturnCurrentTopologyType()
    Dim extUid As UID = New UIDClass()
    extUid.Value = "esriEditorExt.TopologyExtension"
    Dim topologyExt As ITopologyExtension = TryCast(My.ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(extUid), ITopologyExtension)
    If topologyExt.CurrentTopology Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Current no Topology available")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If TypeOf topologyExt.CurrentTopology Is IMapTopology Then
        MsgBox("Current Topology is a map topology")
    Else
        MsgBox("Current Topology is a geodatabase topology")
    End If
End Sub
```

Now I am not sure what I miss for getting the current topology. 
I am using ArcObjects 10.2.1 and vb.net(vs 2012). Please advise me, thanks.

Comment: I think you need to be inside an edit session to be able to access topology.